# Kmeans Clustering - data already grouped as products

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have the following data frame

```
 'data.frame':  88 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ product1: num  212 283 364 357 376 ...
 $ product2: num  5025 4899 4828 4519 4340 ...
 $ product3: num  4295 3745 3790 3868 4066 ...
 $ product4: num  550 557 593 568 556 ...
 $ product5: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product6: num  3484 3205 5243 5183 4784 ...
 $ product7: num  0 0 992 1066 983 ...
 $ product8: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product9: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product10: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product11: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product12: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product13: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product14: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product15: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ product16: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

What I am trying to do is clustering the products based on their sales in 3 groups, for example:

```
cluster 1: products 1, 2, 3, 15, 16
cluster 2: products 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
cluster 3: products 11, 12, 13, 14
```

However, I am struggling writing this on R. What I am getting right now is the following:

```
km <- kmeans(dataFrame, 3)
km$cluster

[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
[41] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
[81] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

The question is, how should I write the code in order to get the 3 clusters for the 16 different products as I printed above?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! For your question, you may consider transposing your dataset (with `t`) so that observations (rows) become parameters (columns) and vice-versa. K-means (and basically any clustering algorithm) performs clustering on observations, not on parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you have 81 observations and 16 variables.

K-means clusters *observations", not variables.

Therefore, you need to transpose your data.

Answer (score 0):

I generated an example of `kmeans` clustering in `R`. Here the dataset consisted of 3 variables (3 columns), and `kmeans` was used to classify the samples in 4 groups. The first output shows the clusters centers for the 3 variables and 4 clusters. Note, if you need to transpose your data, use `t` in `R`. The second output shows the number of samples by cluster.

```
set.seed(1); d <- matrix(rnorm(90), ncol=3)
kd <- kmeans(d, centers=4)
cluster <- kd$cluster
dd <- as.data.frame(cbind(d, cluster))
t(aggregate(dd, by=list(dd$cluster), FUN=mean))[c(1,5)*-1,]

         [,1]        [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
V1  0.8321043 -0.01501747 -0.09144934 -1.8916013
V2  0.0121109 -0.51743551  0.85714652 -0.5389448
V3 -0.4478400  0.17132066  0.99685057 -0.9206161

table(kd$cluster)

 1  2  3  4 
11  6 10  3
```